# What can I get number of clicked element

Tags: javascript, events, numbers, click, element

I have a few elements with identical class names.

How can I get the number of the elements which I clicked with `onclick` events?

For example:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("myclass").length;

for (a=0; a<=x; a++)
{
     // here i want get number of clicked myclass
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by the number of the class?

Comment: Can you show where your onclick event is attached to the element? What function is called?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `indexOf` on an array of `document.getElementsByClassName("myclass")`. You can use `Array.from` or `[].slice.call` to make the array.

Assuming your `click` handlers look like in the snippet below and they *“Do something to `e.target`”* where `e.target` is the element that has been clicked, you can check the `indexOf` `e.target` on the array like this:

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains("myclass")) {
    /*
      The above part could as well look like
      div1.onclick = function(e){…};
      div2.onclick = function(e){…};
      …
    */
    console.log("Do something to %o", e.target);
    console.log("Index of clicked element: %d", Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("myclass")).indexOf(e.target));
  }
});
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="myclass">A0</div>
  <div>B1</div>
  <div class="myclass">A2</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>B3</div>
  <div class="myclass">A4</div>
</div>
<div class="myclass">A5</div>
<div class="myclass">A6</div>
<div>B7</div>
<div class="myclass">A8</div>
```

If you want the index of the element *within the same parent element*, you can instead use:

```
Array.from(e.target.parentNode.children).indexOf(e.target)
```

If you want to restrict the above to elements *with the `myclass` class*, you can use something like:

```
Array.from(e.target.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("myclass")).indexOf(e.target)
```

Or for direct children:

```
Array.from(e.target.parentNode.children).filter(function(elem){
  return elem.classList.contains("myclass");
}).indexOf(e.target)
```

Comment: Thanks. This code is to hard for me, but It works! ;) When I'll have more time, I examine it carefully.

Comment: @KacperŁapiak Well, it’s not really “hard”, it just uses [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods_2) methods. I recommend reading about those. They essentially “replace” `for` loops. Of course you could write the code with `for` loops, but I feel that using `Array` methods instead produces much cleaner code.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture info about the clicked element in the onClick event handler.

Whatever function runs when he click event happens will be passed an event as the first parameter. That event object has a target which will be a reference to the specific element that was clicked.

```
function clickHandler(event) {
   console.log(event.target);
}
```